Help solving $\int_1^e\frac{\ln^2x}{x+x\ln^2x}$
$$\int_1^e\frac{\ln^2x}{x+x\ln^2x}$$
I tried letting $u=\ln^2x$
Meaning $du=\frac{2}{x}\ln xdx \Rightarrow dx=\frac{x}{2\ln x}$
The resulting integral is:
$$\int_0^1\frac{u}{x+xu}\cdot \frac{x}{2\ln x}du=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\frac{u}{x(1+u)}\cdot \frac{x}{\ln x}du$$
I figured the $\ln x$ in the denominator needed to be put in terms of $u$, leaving me with:
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\frac{u}{(1+u)\sqrt{u}}du$$
I'm not sure what to do from here. I think my initial substitution might have been incorrect.

Hint: let $u=\ln(x)$. No need to square it.

Factor x in denominator and use that $\frac{1}{x}dx=d(\ln x)$

$$\int_1^e\frac{\ln^2x}{x(1+\ln^2x)} dx$$
Let $u=\ln x$. So $du = \frac{1}{x} dx$
$$=\int_0^1\frac{u^2}{1+u^2} du = \int_0^1 1-\frac{1}{1+u^2} du = 1-\arctan 1 = \boxed{1-\frac{\pi}{4}}$$

Another approach is to continue with the method that you tried. We have that
$$\int_1^e\frac{\ln^2x}{x+x\ln^2x} = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\frac{u}{(1+u)\sqrt{u}}du = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \sqrt{u} \cdot \frac{1}{1+u} du$$
$$ =  \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \sqrt{u} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k u^k du = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \int_0^1 (-1)^k u^{k+\frac{1}{2}} du = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k} {k+\frac{3}{2}} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k} {2k+3} $$
$$ = 1 - \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k} {2k+1}= \boxed{1-\frac{\pi}{4}}$$

Starting with OP’s last integral
$$
I=\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \frac{u}{(1+u) \sqrt{u}} d u=\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{u}}{1+u} d u
$$
Let $u=\tan^2\theta$, then
$$
\begin{aligned}
I&=  \frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\tan \theta}{\sec ^2 \theta} \cdot 2 \tan \theta \sec ^2 \theta d \theta \\
& =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\left(\sec ^2 \theta-1\right) d \theta \\
& =[\tan \theta-\theta]_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \\
& =1-\frac{\pi}{4} 
\end{aligned}
$$
Wish it helps!

Actually the integral $$\dfrac{1}{2}\int^1_0\dfrac{u}{(u+1)\sqrt{u}}du$$ can be solved by substitution $y=\sqrt{u}$, then the integral becomes $$\int^1_0\dfrac{y^2}{1+y^2}dy=1-\int^1_0\dfrac{1}{1+y^2}dy=1-\left[\arctan{y}\right]^1_0=1-\dfrac{\pi}{4}$$
